# how to add json array to a json object in php

Tags: php, json

I am trying to add a JSON array to a JSON object. My code is like this

```
{
  "status": "True",
  "users": {
    "id": "16",
    "name": "user",
    "email": "user@example.com",
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": "11",
        "name": "frnd1",
        "email": "frnd@example.com"
      },
      {
        "id": "12",
        "name": "frnd2",
        "email": "frnd@example.com"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am getting JSONException while executing following code,

```
 // check for user
    $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($username, $password);
    if ($user != false) {
        // user found
            $response["status"] = "True";
            $userID = $user["id"];
            $response["users"]["id"] = $user["id"];
            $response["users"]["name"] = $user["name"];
            $response["users"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            $result = mysqli_query($con1,"SELECT * 
                                         FROM friends 
                                         where userID = '$userID'");
            $response["users"]["friend"]=array();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
               array_push($response["users"]["friend"], $row);
            }
     }
     echo json_encode($response);
```

i have made $con1 connection in this file.
Can any one point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The JSON you provided is invalid. Check it out in this [validator](http://jsonlint.com)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// check for user
$user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($username, $password);
if ($user != false) {
    // user found
    $response["status"] = "True";
    $userID = $user["id"];
    $response["users"]["id"] = $user["id"];
    $response["users"]["name"] = $user["name"];
    $response["users"]["email"] = $user["email"];
    $result = mysqli_query($con1,"SELECT * 
                                  FROM friends 
                                  WHERE userID = '$userID'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $response["users"]["friends"][] = $row;
    }
 }
 echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: its not working still facing same issue org.json.JSONException

Comment: hey thanks its working now my bad i made mistake in writing table name from "friends" to "friend"

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have an extra `,` after `email`.

Last elements don't need a comma.

**replace**

```
{
    "status": "True",
    "users": {
        "id": "16",
        "name": "user",
        "email": "user@example.com",
        "friends": [
            {
                "id": "11",
                "name": "frnd1",
                "email": "frnd@example.com",//comma not needed here
            },
            {
                "id": "12",
                "name": "frnd2",
                "email": "frnd@example.com",//here too
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**with**

```
{
    "status": "True",
    "users": {
        "id": "16",
        "name": "user",
        "email": "user@example.com",
        "friends": [
            {
                "id": "11",
                "name": "frnd1",
                "email": "frnd@example.com"
            },
            {
                "id": "12",
                "name": "frnd2",
                "email": "frnd@example.com"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```